# Exo player with ffmpeg soft decoder

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, exoplayer

I use exoplayer for stream video `m3u8` and use ads video `mp4 (google ima)`  ( app for tv and android box ) `version 1.5.9` it working perfect with low quantity but with high quantity ( `720p and above and api <23` ) it alway freeze. Problem is hard decoder. I want to change soft decoder like `ffmpeg` and use it for `exoplayer`.

Some one have sample or tutorial for it please help me.